# Replacing adaptive average 2d pooling with regular average 2d pooling

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, onnx

I have a PyTorch model [(PoolNet)](https://github.com/backseason/PoolNet/blob/master/networks/deeplab_resnet.py) that uses an adaptive average pooling layer in the following manner:

```
ppms = []
for ii in [1, 3, 5]:
    ppms.append(nn.Sequential(
                nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(ii),
                nn.Conv2d(512, 512, 1, 1, bias=False),
                nn.ReLU(inplace=True)))

self.ppms = nn.ModuleList(ppms)
```

I want to adapt this model for a fixed input size in order to later convert it to ONNX format. I assume an input tensor shape of 3 x 1600 x 1000 (Channels x Width x Height). So, I replaced `nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(ii)` with
`nn.AvgPool2d((1000//ii, 1600//ii))`.
I have also verified that the input shape to the average pooling is the input shape of the entire model - (3x1600x100)

In addition, I've verified (elsewhere) that the output tensor shapes after pooling for both versions are identical.

However, when I run torch.onnx.export, the second version crashes with an exception:

> File "C:\REPOSITORIES\poolnet2TF\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\pooling.py", line 599, in forward
> self.padding, self.ceil_mode, self.count_include_pad, self.divisor_override)
> RuntimeError: Given input size: (512x63x101). Calculated output size: (512x0x0). Output size is too small

which means that contrary to my assumption, the output tensors after pooling for both versions are not the same. What's going on?

Comment: You need to use the input shape to the average pooling layer not the input to your model!

Comment: The input shape to the average pooling layer is the input shape for the model. This was also verified. Thanks, I'll update the question.

Comment: can you also add the whole model definition?

Comment: It's in the link in the question itself

Comment: I gave it a try and I didnt face any issues with the default arch, except for the bilinear which seems to not be implemented by onnx yet! which version of pytorch are you using? how are you doing the conversion? are you specifying a specific op version?